# spatially join nested polygons when nesting is not perfect

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two shapefiles and two problems.

1. These should be nested polygons, but the smaller ones (level 3) don't fit exactly inside the bigger ones (level 2).

[image]

2. Even if they were a perfect match, there is no key that that I can use to join them. The smaller polygon file is missing the field `level2_code` that maps to `level2_code` in the bigger polygon file.

What's the best spatial joining approach (I'm working with {`sf`}) to assign the smaller ones (level 3) 1:1 to the bigger ones (level 2)? I'd like to go with majority rule. If a smaller polygon is split between 2 bigger polygons 60/40, I want to assign it to the polygon that captures 60% of it's area.

Here are the example shapefiles:

```
devtools::source_gist("3bf2ed930868a2807a58b5c04f700a1b")
```

```
example_bigger

Simple feature collection with 27 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 6.63908 ymin: 5.194552 xmax: 7.432286 ymax: 5.938931
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 27 x 2
   level2_code                                                             geometry
         <dbl>                                                   <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
 1           1 (((7.321909 5.40493, 7.321575 5.401201, 7.322123 5.399188, 7.322649…
 2           2 (((7.308938 5.617926, 7.308858 5.613426, 7.308925 5.611024, 7.30905…
 3           3 (((7.361156 5.714312, 7.358485 5.713518, 7.354733 5.711535, 7.35242…
 4           4 (((7.388033 5.510387, 7.387133 5.507236, 7.385656 5.503802, 7.38476…
 5           5 (((7.178212 5.808309, 7.178176 5.806321, 7.17929 5.803731, 7.18097 …
 6           6 (((7.202845 5.920962, 7.206038 5.924097, 7.20778 5.925807, 7.209518…
 7           7 (((7.015881 5.895269, 7.015242 5.890107, 7.012308 5.886351, 7.01131…
 8           8 (((7.381608 5.705609, 7.382155 5.703596, 7.382979 5.70072, 7.384001…
 9           9 (((7.209132 5.60738, 7.211122 5.605943, 7.213938 5.604008, 7.216109…
10          10 (((7.265981 5.744175, 7.26594 5.740849, 7.265327 5.737696, 7.265033…
# … with 17 more rows
```

```
example_smaller

Simple feature collection with 348 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 6.63908 ymin: 5.194552 xmax: 7.432286 ymax: 5.938931
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 348 x 2
   level3_code                                                             geometry
         <dbl>                                                   <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
 1           1 (((7.153985 5.786385, 7.151873 5.777959, 7.155913 5.768072, 7.14011…
 2           2 (((7.353153 5.870928, 7.34829 5.856211, 7.342018 5.842341, 7.314459…
 3           3 (((7.235717 5.510277, 7.235989 5.5113, 7.236185 5.512454, 7.23656 5…
 4           4 (((6.947564 5.754671, 6.946301 5.755986, 6.945236 5.756682, 6.95680…
 5           5 (((7.001083 5.550417, 7.00185 5.55142, 7.002059 5.552684, 7.002277 …
 6           6 (((7.043065 5.77843, 7.04189 5.777916, 7.041544 5.777805, 7.041274 …
 7           7 (((7.002059 5.552684, 7.00185 5.55142, 7.001083 5.550417, 6.999884 …
 8           8 (((7.262075 5.526829, 7.262966 5.528058, 7.264392 5.528519, 7.26564…
 9           9 (((7.07199 5.735022, 7.070997 5.735426, 7.063343 5.736378, 7.055127…
10          10 (((7.265549 5.575613, 7.265963 5.574931, 7.266252 5.574365, 7.26567…
# … with 338 more rows
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `largest=TRUE` argument in `st_join`?

Comment: Wow, @Skaqqs I was not expecting something so simple: `sf::st_join(example_smaller, example_bigger, largest=TRUE)`

Comment: ...did it work?? :)

Comment: Yes! Quite nicely.

Comment: Ok great! Good luck